# How to extract key and its corresponding type of a property for usage in a new type?

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this:

```
interface Filters {
    active: boolean
    name: string
    tags: string[]
}
```

and I have a Function `function setFilter(change: FilterChange<Filters>)` which I want to call like:

```
// Good:
setFilter({filter: 'active', value: true})

setFilter({filter: 'name', value: 'a string'})

setFilter({filter: 'tags', value: ['some', 'strings']})

// Bad
setFilter({filter: 'active', value: 'wrong type'})

setFilter({filter: 'unknown_property', value: '?'})
```

I struggle to define the generic type `FilterChange`. Here is what I tried so far:

```
interface FilterChange<T, K = keyof T> {
    filter: K
    value: T[K] //Error: Type K cannot be used to index type T
}
```

When I change it to:

```
interface FilterChange<T, K extends keyof T> {
    filter: K
    value: T[K]
}
```

I have to define the specific key explicitly like `function setFilter(change: FilterChange<Filters, 'active'>)` which is not what I want. I want TypeScript to infer the type from the `filter` property. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you actually need `T` to be generic, why not just use `Filters` and only vary `K`?

Comment: It seems like you're focusing on `FilterChange` when you should be looking at making `setFilter()` generic in `K` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nno56m).  If that's what you want someone can write an answer (maybe @jonrsharpe since his comment is talking about the same thing). If not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz, many thanks, you're right, that is what I want. I find it interesting that it can infer K and use as index when defined on the Function. I would appreciate if someone could express that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your definition of `FilterChange`, at least after you [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to `keyof T`.  The issue you're having is that your `setFilter()` function isn't of the right kind. The easiest way to get the behavior you want is to make `setFilter()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `K`, as follows:

```
declare function
  setFilter<K extends keyof Filters>(change: FilterChange<Filters, K>): void;
```

Now when you call `setFilter()` the compiler will try to infer `K` from the argument... meaning that the `filter` property will fix `K`, and then the `value` property will be checked against `Filters[K]`.  Like so:

```
setFilter({ filter: 'active', value: true }) // okay
setFilter({ filter: 'name', value: 'a string' }) // okay
setFilter({ filter: 'tags', value: ['some', 'strings'] }) // okay
setFilter({ filter: 'active', value: 'wrong type' }) // error
// -------------------------> ~~~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
setFilter({ filter: 'unknown_property', value: '?' }) // error
// -------> ~~~~~~
// Type '"unknown_property"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Filters'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADaSgZ2QbwFgAoZZRMYANwgC5kAjAeyYwjhBLJDgFs7kOMFFABzLsjBxROekJEhRAbQC6JAL4kSobPCRpM2AMIALDqIgAeACoAaZAGlkEAB6QQAEzwBrCAE8mGGRrAD4CCRhDaHoHCSo4DABXAWslBzViTWISDwgEDDgoFBhEkARKJk5SQQgwdCxoSydXdy9kXwCg+uwcEIAKBDNFAW7oU3MrUdx7BxCASnoqJmAPAG4tbOIcWqm+-GRIhqh6AHIKaggT+3ikgWFk5HU55AB6F+Qmbzg-Em26qKgewOANOPH4V2QN2SpzggmEYhOj2ebw+Xx+Wx2AKBh2wpykMghUIEShOOCY4PspPhihwJxUSNe70+31+mKO2JByDO5QuhIS0K5AHcoJVRJI-AAHS4MlHQEVQEgogC0KtVavVGrVYQAfrrdYr3tZJSgqQpRIjgHgQEwwOQcDhgKIeAw2JImOKpVzmKx2CATgA6Vn-dn7HHRLmlbzWwUgAD6EpFUqgYD8fNupwA-IinoznFB5QbkJqdXr9cQUUbPScAESR6NxhNMJMp6sWq02u0Op1wF0oMDulNVjqBAxHWmBzZAA)